# ESET NOD32 Antivirus error on update - base file missing

Tags: windows-server-2008, anti-virus, update

I have taken over the administration of a Windows Server 2008 64bit installation. The server has ESET NOD32 Antivirus Business Edition v4.2 installed.

The server hasn't been updating its virus signature database in the last few days, and upon trying to do a manual update, I get the following error message:

"Base file missing".

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: eset base file missing]

I've tried to find a solution for this problem on the ESET website, as well as on Google, but this hasn't been successful.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't find out what was causing this problem, but upon advice from ESET support, I re-installed ESET NOD32 and cleared the Update Cache.

This fixed the problem. Let's hope it doesn't crop up again.